# Failing to open file, am I linking it wrong? Or is Android Studio not seeing it for some reason?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a simple .txt file with just a couple lines in right now, each line has a word then a comma then another word, representing a very simplistic username , password bank. For some reason though I cant get the File to open to read from it.

Here is my code that I'm using....

```
try {
    final String PATH = "src\\main\\assets\\passwords.txt";
    Log.w("myApp", "passed");
    List<String> user_password = FileUtils.readLines(new File(PATH));
    Log.w("myApp", "passed2");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<Credentials> credentials = (List<Credentials>) CollectionUtils.collect(user_password, new Transformer() {
        @Override
        public Object transform(Object input) {
            String cred = (String) input;
            String parsed[] = cred.split(",");
            Log.w("myApp", parsed[0]);
            return new Credentials(parsed[0], parsed[1]);
            //return credential;
        }
    });
    user = (Credentials) CollectionUtils.find(credentials, new Predicate() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
            Credentials c = (Credentials) object;
            return c.getUserName().equals(userName);
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print(e);
    Log.w("MyApp", "failed");
}
```

I've tried putting the *passwords.txt* file in different places but that doesn't seem to work either.

[image: Here's the assets folder with the .txt file in it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare I was able to achieve what I was trying to do by using InputStream and then also IOUtils to read everything into the List.

```
try {
        InputStream iS = this.getAssets().open("passwords.txt");
        List<String> user_password = IOUtils.readLines(iS);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<Credentials> credentials = (List<Credentials>) CollectionUtils.collect(user_password, new Transformer() {
            @Override
            public Object transform(Object input) {
                String cred = (String) input;
                String parsed[] = cred.split(",");
                return new Credentials(parsed[0], parsed[1]);
            }
        });
        user = (Credentials) CollectionUtils.find(credentials, new Predicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
                Credentials c = (Credentials) object;
                return c.getUserName().equals(userName);
            }
        });
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing wrong to file in assets folder. It has to be smth like:

```
file:///android_asset/myfoldername/myfilename
```

in your particular case it's `file:///android_asset/passwords.txt`, though you have to keep in mind that it's always read only file

Answer (score 1):

```
final String PATH = "src\\main\\assets\\passwords.txt";
```

That's not going to work. Android is not Windows, and an Android device is not your Windows development PC.

First, `\` is the Windows path separator. On OS X, Linux, and Android, the path separator is `/`.

Second, `src\main\assets\passwords.txt` is a file in your project. It is not a file on the filesystem of the Android device.

To access assets, use `AssetManager` to open an `InputStream()`. You can get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on any handy `Context`, such as your activity. Then, for your asset, call `open("passwords.txt")` on the `AssetManager` to get the `InputStream`, that you can then use to read in the data.

Comment: Thanks... I did 'InputStream stream = this.getAssets().open("passwords.txt");' 
'BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new inputStream(stream));'
'String line = reader.readLine();' which successfully opened and read the first line as expected... Is there anyway do you know to use the FileUtils instead of BufferedReader?

Comment: @Shane: Since there is no `FileUtils` in the Android SDK, I cannot really help you with that, sorry.